# Macro does not run correctly when executed in a combined macro

Tags: vba, excel, formula

When I run this macro on its own it executes correctly:

```
Sub StateBIPDData()
Dim sheet_name As Range
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("B:B")
If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
    Exit For
Else
With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
'***********************
'Format BI data for states
'***********************
'Countrywide Earned Car Years
.Cells(14, 2) = (Cells(53, 11))
.Cells(15, 2) = (Cells(49, 11))
.Cells(16, 2) = (Cells(45, 11))
.Cells(17, 2) = (Cells(41, 11))
.Cells(18, 2) = (Cells(37, 11))
'Paid Claim Frequency (Claim Frequency) = (Number of Paid Claims ÷ Earned House Years) ×     100
.Cells(14, 3) = (Cells(53, 17))
.Cells(15, 3) = (Cells(49, 17))
.Cells(16, 3) = (Cells(45, 17))
.Cells(17, 3) = (Cells(40, 17))
.Cells(18, 3) = (Cells(37, 17))
'.Range("C14:C18").Copy
'.Range("C14:C18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Average Loss (Claim Severity)  = Paid Losses ÷ Number of Paid Claims
.Cells(14, 4) = (Cells(53, 15))
.Cells(15, 4) = (Cells(49, 15))
.Cells(16, 4) = (Cells(45, 15))
.Cells(17, 4) = (Cells(41, 15))
.Cells(18, 4) = (Cells(37, 15))
'.Range("D14:D18").Copy
'.Range("D14:D18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Pure Premium (Loss Cost) = Paid Losses ÷ Earned House Years
.Cells(14, 5) = (Cells(53, 19))
.Cells(15, 5) = (Cells(49, 19))
.Cells(16, 5) = (Cells(45, 19))
.Cells(17, 5) = (Cells(41, 19))
.Cells(18, 5) = (Cells(37, 19))
'.Range("E14:E18").Copy
'.Range("E14:E18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'.Range("K37:S56").Clear
'***********************
'Format PD data for states
'***********************
'Paid Claim Frequency (Claim Frequency) = (Number of Paid Claims ÷ Earned House Years) × 100
.Cells(14, 6) = (Cells(30, 13))
.Cells(15, 6) = (Cells(26, 13))
.Cells(16, 6) = (Cells(22, 13))
.Cells(17, 6) = (Cells(18, 13))
.Cells(18, 6) = (Cells(14, 13))
'.Range("F14:F18").Copy
'.Range("F14:F18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Average Loss (Claim Severity)  = Paid Losses ÷ Number of Paid Claims
.Cells(14, 7) = (Cells(30, 11))
.Cells(15, 7) = (Cells(26, 11))
.Cells(16, 7) = (Cells(22, 11))
.Cells(17, 7) = (Cells(18, 11))
.Cells(18, 7) = (Cells(14, 11))
'.Range("G14:G18").Copy
'.Range("G14:G18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Pure Premium (Loss Cost) = Paid Losses ÷ Earned House Years
.Cells(14, 8) = (Cells(30, 15))
.Cells(15, 8) = (Cells(26, 15))
.Cells(16, 8) = (Cells(22, 15))
.Cells(17, 8) = (Cells(18, 15))
.Cells(18, 8) = (Cells(14, 15))
'.Range("H14:H18").Copy
'.Range("H14:H18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'.Range("K14:O33").Clear
'***********************
'Calculate 'Number of BI Claims Per 100 PD Claims"
'***********************
.Cells(14, 9) = (Cells(14, 3) / Cells(14, 6)) * 100
.Cells(15, 9) = (Cells(15, 3) / Cells(15, 6)) * 100
.Cells(16, 9) = (Cells(16, 3) / Cells(16, 6)) * 100
.Cells(17, 9) = (Cells(17, 3) / Cells(17, 6)) * 100
.Cells(18, 9) = (Cells(18, 3) / Cells(18, 6)) * 100
'.Range("I14:I18").Copy
'.Range("I14:I18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
    End If
Next sheet_name
End Sub
```

Although, when I run the code in a combined macro the code doesn't execute properly.

In fact, nothing happens at all and the target cells are left blank. The data for the source cells is present.

Any thoughts as to why the values are not showing up in the target cells?

Here is the code of the combined macro:

```
Sub DataAutomation_AITrends()
GetSourceSheets
CreateCwBIDataCalculate
InsertRowAllStates
CopyPasteBIPDPIPData
StateBIPDData
StatePIPData
DeleteWorkSheets
Percent_change_CalculationAllSheets
On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code uses unqulified calls to `Cells()`, so it's highly dependent on what the activesheet is at the time it runs.  I'd suggest starting off by fully qualifying all those Cells() references with a specific worksheet.

Comment: How do I fully qualify the Cells() references?

Comment: In your code `.Cells(14, 2)` refers to `Sheets(sheet_name.Value)`, but `Cells(53,11)` refers to whatever happens to be the active sheet. If you're copying from a specific sheet then do something like `Dim ws as WorkSheet: Set ws = Sheets("shettNameHere")` then you can use (eg) `ws.Cells(53,11)`

Comment: Even if the data in Cells(53,11) and Cells(14,2) is on the same worksheet?

Comment: The target data and the source data is on the same sheet. I just need to essentially move the data into different cells on the same sheet.

Comment: Then you just need to add the period. And you don't need the parentheses around that. `(Cells(53, 11))` should be `.Cells(53, 11)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
Sub PercentChangeCalBIPD()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sheet_name As Range
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("H:H")
    If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
    With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
'90-20## Percent Change
iRow = 14
Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
While Cell_val <> ""
iRow = iRow + 3
Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 1) = "1990-2012"
'Column B,2

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
While Cell_val <> ""
iRow = iRow + 3
Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 2) = "=((B14/VLOOKUP(1990, A14:B46, 2,FALSE))-1)"
End Sub
```